# C# How to run my two function at same time asynchronously

Tags: c#

Below is sample program i have written. i am learning usage of async/await.
when i execute the code then i saw first `GetAllTheCats` execute and when complete then `GetAllTheFood` execute. so this is not parallel. Tell me how could i run two routine at same time asynchronously which will update two different label control. if possible please restructure my code.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => GetAllTheCats());
            await Task.Run(() => GetAllTheFood());
        }

        public string GetAllTheCats()
        {
            // Do stuff, like hit the Db, spin around, dance, jump, etc...
            // It all takes some time.
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return "";
        }

        public string GetAllTheFood()
        {
            // Do more stuff, like hit the Db, nom nom noms...
            // It all takes some time.
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            return "";
        }
```

Comment: I found dozens of duplicates by googling just "C# run tasks in parallel". You should do more researching before asking a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetAllTheCats());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetAllTheFood());

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

then

```
Console.WriteLine(task1.Result);
```

or

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. hwo to know both the function call ended....do i need to use continue with? if yes then how can i use continuewith with WhenAll ?

Comment: that's just how await works. Sounds like you may need to read up on how async/await works in C#

Comment: await Task.WhenAll  means wait untill all task get finished then continue

Comment: how to use continuewith when fire multiple routine by task? is it possible?

Comment: `ContinueWith` means you need to wait when the 1st task will finished and continue the 2nd task with the results of the 1st one. `WhenAll` means your tasks independent from each other.

Comment: IF you want to learn usage of await vs ContinueWith [Read This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/difference-between-await-and-continuewith-keyword-in-C-Sharp/)